# Getting less than half download speed after new modem and internet plan, only happens on one computer, but upload speed is just fine

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Good day,

My household recently upgraded from a 100/10 up/down megabit plan to a 400/20 plan. We got a new modem, and after getting everything connected, every device I have done a speedtest on usually shows around 250 down and 22 up. I know getting less than 400 down is normal, but when I use my personal computer, I get between 70-90 down and the normal 22 up. I am incredibly confused as to why this would be happening on only my computer.

I have:

- Tried unplugging both router and modem
- Ran netsh winsock reset in powershell
- Uninstalled and reinstalled WiFi adapter driver
- We do have a mesh WiFi extender that my computer was connecting to before, but I blocked it from connecting to the extender and it made no difference, only gave a slightly better ping by 3ms.

The router we have is a Netgear Nighthawk R8000 model, and another problem I have been having is I cannot connect to the second 5ghz band on the computer either, just says cannot connect whenever I try, but every other device I have tried connects just fine. I will try to fix that another day, getting the download speeds fixed is my current priority.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, as I tend to be the one using the internet the most on my computer and when we had the 100/10 plan before I usually averaged 114 down so getting at most 90 when I should be getting ~250 is very frustrating. I am also a Computer Science college student who works in tech sales, so I am open to any advanced suggestions anyone may have. Please & thank you.

Edit: Now for some reason despite me changing nothing I am getting 30/20. This is so confusing.

Comment: I suggest trying a top grade USB Wireless Adapter to help you determine if your current Wireless adapter needs upgrading.

Comment: I knew I forgot something, my current wifi adapter is a [tp-link archer t6e](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/pci-adapter/archer-t6e/)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem. I was on the verge of just doing a full Windows reset and I had one, final, desperate thought. I fiddled with the WiFi adapters antennae and making sure they were fully screwed in, and tried tilting them a few different ways. Suddenly, as my computer was redownloading Windows 10 to perform the reset, I had Task Manager open, and suddenly my download speed skyrocketed to 100. I quickly cancelled the download, and tried to connect to my second 5ghz band, and it worked without any problems. I tried the speed test again, and this time I hit the full 400/22. So, I am very glad I killed two birds with one stone but disappointed it was something so stupid and easy.